# problem mapping with turtlebot at slope area

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there
Im doing the gmapping with turtlebot. now i want explain my place condition.There are two side and just next to each other.one is flat ground and one is slope ground. when im doing gmapping at flat ground it working fine, after that i move my turtlebot to the slope ground. when the robot going down, it working fine and show the right position  in rvis.But when the turtlebot moving up. the turtlebot in rvis going crazy. it show the turtlebot position jump to the flat ground. can somebody explain to me why this happen. thank you

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199332/problem-mapping-with-turtlebot-at-slope-area/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on 2014-12-11**:
How big is the slope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The slope probably is getting detected as an obstacle and amcl is trying to update the position in the map.

When you drive down the slope the area is detected as free space. When you try to drive up the slope the sensor detects it as obstacle because it is on the height of an obstacle. This doesn't fit the internal map which was generated before (the area should be free). So the robot basically thinks his actual position is different than what he thought, thus relocating himself in the map.

It also could be because the robot maybe slides on the slope and the odometry is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) with karma: 88 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on 2014-12-13**:
the slope is really big....hmmm...
is there any information and change in node, rqt graph or other else..because i need to give good reason for this problem

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on 2014-12-14**:
To make sure it is that problem, put the turtlebot on the lower end of the slope and let it rotate. You should see walls getting added where the slope is. You can also visualize the "laser scanner" of the turtlebot in rviz